# Is smoke a problem like zeya?

Tags: meat-and-milk

I know that zeya (steam, kinda) is a problem in cooking milk and meat. Also heat can be a problem.

My friend recently burned some burgers in his oven (we think it was a grease fire), and watched copious amounts of smoke come out of the vents. (the fire went out quickly and everyone's okay just his kitchen smells now) The vents are placed right next to the stove, upon which he had a cold milchig pan.

- does that milchig pan need to be kashered now?

Comment: Sounds like Taam Lifgam to me

Comment: @DoubleAA, yeah, but smoke isn't always. Which means this question is too specific to the friend's situation and should be closed as [rfפ](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3406).

Comment: if it's smoke, there's a good chance it is considered as ash. Even if it is, the problem still remains whether  the smoke also included steam. So you have two questions: 1. the status of smoke; and 2: whether there is a problem of zeya in your particular case.

Comment: @msh210 I don't really know hilchos kashrus that well, but could smoke from a grease fire be not taam lifgam? I understand if you're smoking meats or fish, that the smoke might have a desirable taam, but I'm pretty sure that this smoke would impart a bad taste, if it imparts a taste at all.

Comment: @Shokhet, I was thinking of smoking meat or fish as likely not _lifgam_. (Um. I mean "as unlikely _lifgam_", not "as likely _nat lifgam_".)

Comment: Sorry, @msh210. I misplaced several words in my comment. In the final sentence, the first "the smoke" is smoking meat and fish (not *nat lifgam*), while the second "this smoke" is Samuel's friend's grease fire (probably *nosein taam lifgam*).

Comment: whats the difference between not lifgam and nat lifgam?? i'm confused.

Comment: @Samuel I assume you know what the English word "not" means. "*Nat*" stands for the Hebrew נ"ט, which in turn is short for נותן טעם (*nosein taam*), that which gives a taste.